# Sometimes there is a link error under VS2012, sometimes not

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation

Today I've got a strange link error under VS 2012. When I tried to build my solution after some coding I got link error (LNK2001). When I canceled changes just by commenting added lines, the project builds. With some tries I got a strange thing. (next lines describes my actions in actual order)

When I build project with all lines, I'm getting LNK2001.

When I comment first constructor for GeneticNetworkRealisation - I'm getting LNK2001.

When I comment second constructor for GeneticNetwork - error disappears.

But when I return this line back to code - there is still no error.

So, this means that two identical code has different link success. Any ideas of how to fix this? Simplified code and errors:

NeuralNetwork.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Neuron.h"
#include "NeuralLayer.h"

struct Topology {
    // some variables
};

class NeuralNetwork {

public:

    NeuralNetwork(const Topology & topology);
    NeuralNetwork(const NeuralNetwork & nn) : layers(nn.layers) {}

    virtual ~NeuralNetwork() {}

protected:

    std::vector<NeuralLayer> layers;

};
```

GeneticNetwork.h

```
#pragma once

#include "NeuralNetwork.h"

class GeneticNetwork : public NeuralNetwork {

public:

    GeneticNetwork(const Topology & topology) : NeuralNetwork(topology) {}
    GeneticNetwork(const GeneticNetwork & gnn) : NeuralNetwork(gnn) {}

    virtual std::vector<double> getNetworkGeneticCode() const = 0;
    virtual void mutate() = 0;
    virtual NeuralNetwork crossingOver(const NeuralNetwork & nn) const = 0;

    virtual ~GeneticNetwork() {}
};
```

GeneticNetworkRealisation.h

```
#pragma once

#include "GeneticNetwork.h"
#include "URNG.h"

struct MutationParameters {
    // some parameters
};

const MutationParameters DEFAULT_MUTATION_PARAMS = {/*...*/};

class GeneticNetworkRealisation : public GeneticNetwork {

public:

    GeneticNetworkRealisation(const GeneticNetworkRealisation & gnn) :
            GeneticNetwork(gnn), random(gnn.random), mutationParams(gnn.mutationParams) {}

    GeneticNetworkRealisation(const Topology & topology, URNG urng = URNG(),
            const MutationParameters & mutationParameters = DEFAULT_MUTATION_PARAMS) :
            GeneticNetwork(topology), random(urng), mutationParams(mutationParameters) {}

    virtual std::vector<double> getNetworkGeneticCode() const override;
    virtual void mutate() override;
    virtual NeuralNetwork crossingOver(const NeuralNetwork & nn) const override;

    virtual ~GeneticNetworkRealisation() {}

protected:

    URNG & random;
    MutationParameters mutationParams;

};
```

GeneticNetworkRealisation.cpp

```
#include "GeneticNetworkRealisation.h"

void GeneticNetworkRealisation::mutate() {
    // code
}

std::vector<double> GeneticNetworkRealisation::getNetworkGeneticCode() const {
    // code
}

NeuralNetwork GeneticNetworkRealisation::crossingOver(const NeuralNetwork & nn) const {
    // code
}
```

Errors:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ""public: virtual class std::vector<double,class std::allocator<double> > __thiscall GeneticNetworkRealisation::getNetworkGeneticCode(void)const " (?getNetworkGeneticCode@GeneticNetworkRealisation@@UBE?AV?$vector@NV?$allocator@N@std@@@std@@XZ)"
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ""public: virtual void __thiscall GeneticNetworkRealisation::mutate(void)" (?mutate@GeneticNetworkRealisation@@UAEXXZ)"
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ""public: virtual class NeuralNetwork __thiscall GeneticNetworkRealisation::crossingOver(class NeuralNetwork const &)const " (?crossingOver@GeneticNetworkRealisation@@UBE?AVNeuralNetwork@@ABV2@@Z)"
```

Comment: you should not post screenshots anyhow. post code instead

Comment: As well as error messages as text...